Why won't my VBA code run in personal.xlsb but will work in thisworkbook section?
I wanted to know why the below code runs fine when I use it on the ThisWorkbook section but when I try to run it on personal.xlsb it doesn't work at all?
Sub CleanData()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim KeyWords As Variant
    Dim KeyWord As Variant
    Dim deleteRow As Boolean
    
    ' Define keywords to be deleted
    KeyWords = Array("lifeworksadmin.com", "lifeworks.com", "soft deleted", "deactivated", "shared", "limited", "dependant")
    
    ' Loop through all worksheets in the workbook
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            ' Find the last used row and column
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            
            ' Loop through each row in reverse order
            For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
                deleteRow = False ' Reset deleteRow flag
                
                ' Check each cell in the row for keywords
                For j = 1 To LastCol
                    For Each KeyWord In KeyWords
                        If InStr(1, LCase(.Cells(i, j).Value), LCase(KeyWord)) > 0 Then
                            deleteRow = True ' Set deleteRow flag
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next KeyWord
                    If deleteRow Then Exit For ' Exit loop if keyword found
                Next j
                
                ' Delete the row if any keyword is found
                If deleteRow Then .Rows(i).Delete
            Next i
            
            ' Auto adjust column width
            .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
            
            ' Auto adjust row height
            .Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub

I had tried adding the code to the ThisWorkbook section and it works fine but when I try to add it onto the personal.xlsb section it never runs.

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets is referring to the xlsb, you want activeworkbook

@Warcupine you type too fast :)
